# Bibtex/Biblatex and alphastyle: choose year as first online appearance

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

I wrote an article in 2018, improved it in another paper in 2019, and published the first paper much later in 2021. As I'm using the alpha style, it sounds weird to say that [Me21] appeared before [Me19]. As a result, I'd like to display [Me18] instead of [Me21], and precise in the bibliography that it appeared online in 2018 and was published in 2021. And I guess it's somehow possible since it was done in other papers:

[image]

What is the proper way to do that? I'm interested by both Bibtex and BibLatex solutions, and ideally would love this to be compatible with Zotero so that I don't need too much dirty tuning when copying an entry from Zotero.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@article{ABCD,
  title = {My title},
  author = {Its, Me},
  date = {2021-03},
  journaltitle = {My journal},
  volume = {1},
  number = {2},
  pages = {3},
  note = {First online appearance in arxiv:1234 (2018).},
}
\end{filecontents}


% BibLatex > Bibtex
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=trad-alpha]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

I'd like to see [Its18] instead of~\cite{ABCD}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `biblatex`, you can use the `shorthand` field to specify the citation label directly:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{biblio.bib}
@article{ABCD,
  title = {My title},
  author = {Its, Me},
  date = {2021-03},
  shorthand = {Its18},
  journaltitle = {My journal},
  volume = {1},
  number = {2},
  pages = {3},
  note = {First online appearance in arxiv:1234 (2018).},
}
\end{filecontents}

% BibLatex > Bibtex
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=trad-alpha]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

I'd like to see [Its18], and you do~\cite{ABCD}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, thanks! And what about bibtex?

Comment: @tobiasBora I'd doubt (though I don't know) that this field is available for `bibtex`... Either way, I don't know a `bibtex` solution.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a universal solution that works across all BibTeX and `biblatex` styles.

For `biblatex`'s `alphabetic` style I would probably put the year in which the article was first published online as `origdate`. By default `origdate` is not used by the standard styles, but we can make it appear in the alphabetic label with `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=trad-alpha]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{origyear}
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ABCD,
  title        = {My title},
  author       = {Its, Me},
  date         = {2021-03},
  origdate     = {2018},
  journaltitle = {My journal},
  volume       = {1},
  number       = {2},
  pages        = {3},
  note         = {First online appearance in arxiv:1234 (2018).},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
I'd like to see [Its18] instead of~\cite{ABCD}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: I’d like to see [Its18] instead of [Its18].]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I also like this solution a lot (sadly I can't accept two answers). The other answer is maybe simpler, and this one more customizable, I needed to make a choice. By any chance do you know how to adapt it to bibtex?